# Highlight clicked li jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to highlight li elements, and I know there is definitely a much efficient way to do what I am trying to do. On click highlight the selected li, the approach i used is not very efficient as you can see. if I have 20 li's it doesn't make sense to do this.

Html:

```
<ul>
<li id="level1"><a>Light</a></li>
<li id="level2"><a>Medium</a></li>
<li id="level3"><a>Enterprise</a></li>
</ul>
```

Code:
applicationLicenseLevel is a number passed in(1,2 or 3)

This switch is called within a document.ready().

```
 switch (applicationLicenseLevel) {
                    case 1:
                        $('#level1').addClass('activeLicenseLevel');
                        $('#level2').removeClass('activeLicenseLevel');
                        $('#level3').removeClass('activeLicenseLevel');
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $('#level2').addClass('activeLicenseLevel');
                        $('#level1').removeClass('activeLicenseLevel');
                        $('#level3').removeClass('activeLicenseLevel');
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $('#level3').addClass('activeLicenseLevel');
                        $('#level1').removeClass('activeLicenseLevel');
                        $('#level2').removeClass('activeLicenseLevel');
                        break;
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider removing all of them with `ID` attributes that start with "level" using the [starts-with selector `^=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) in jQuery and then add the class to your current one :

```
// Remove the active class from every element that starts with "level"
$('[id^="level"]').removeClass('activeLicenseLevel');
$('#level' + applicationLicenseLevel).addClass('activeLicenseLevel');
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not set id for that 20+ `li` elements. That will create references for each and every element with id in global scope for named access.

Suggestion : Just give it to that `UL`. That too if it is needed to differentiate from other `UL`s.

```
var lis = $("ul li").click(function(){
  lis.removeClass("activeLicenseLevel");
  $(this).addClass("activeLicenseLevel");
});
```

I haven't noticed your real case. For your case you can do like,

```
var lis = $("ul li").removeClass("activeLicenseLevel");
lis.eq(applicationLicenseLevel).addClass("activeLicenseLevel");
//.eq(index) will get the element based on the supplied index from the element collection
```

Do not set id unnecessarily, I have given the reason why in the above part of this answer.